# show patients that had a certain type of diagnose

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

I have a patient database. In that database i have a table "diagnosetypes" and a table with dossiers with a patient that received a certain diagnose.

In my diagnose form i have a list of diagnoses and now i want to add a listbox with a filter on all patients/dossiers that had this certain diagnose when that diagnose is selected in the combobox.

this is my current code

```
Public Class Diagnoses

    Private Sub Diagnoses_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Tbl_DossiersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Dossiers)
        Me.Tbl_DiagnosesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Diagnoses)
        Dim dt = Tbl_DiagnosesBindingSource
        cboxDiagnose.DataSource = dt
        cboxDiagnose.DisplayMember = "Diag_Type"
        txtDiagnoseBeschrijving.Text = dt(0)("Diag_Type").ToString
        cboxDiagnose.Focus()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CboxDiagnose_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxDiagnose.SelectionChangeCommitted
        txtDiagnoseBeschrijving.Text = DirectCast(cboxDiagnose.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("Diag_Beschrijving").ToString

    End Sub
    Private Sub CboxDiagnose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxDiagnose.Click
        RefreshData()
    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnAddDiagnose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddDiagnose.Click
        FormMakeDiagnoseType.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshData()
        Try
            Me.Tbl_DiagnosesBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
            Me.Tbl_DiagnosesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Diagnoses)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Refresh Data Error: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                   MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Record Failed!")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

edit: I changed my code to look like this as a way of trying to accomplish it myself , but i won't work.

```
Private Sub Diagnoses_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\GoogleDrive\EINDWERK VBNET\PatientenDatabase.accdb")
       cn.Open()
       Dim cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Dossiers WHERE OZ_ID.value = cboxDiagnose.text", cn)
       Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
       dr = cmmd.ExecuteReader
       Do While dr.Read
           lboxPat_Diagcombo.Items.Add(dr("Rel_naam"))
       Loop
       cn.Close()
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?  How exactly are you looking to do this?  I'm guessing you want to use Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Dossiers.Filter  or did you have some other method in mind.  Really would be helpful to see the tbl_Dossiers table definition  and how it's related to tbl_Diagnoses if you're wanting help with the filter expressions

Comment: Could you provide more details about your question? It will help others make a test.

Comment: i have a dropbox link with a copy to the access file 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4gudk8lwxtjahiq/AACz69ocFWIlU7hiTlQxbviLa?dl=0
maybe the database file can shed light on what i mean? or the possiblities?

Comment: Unfortunately,I can't find table "diagnosetypes" in the database file. Besides, 'OZ_ID' and 'Diag_Type' have completely different values in the database, so you cannot select any values in 'WHERE OZ_ID.value = cboxDiagnose.text'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found something that works!

defined a binding source in code
then linked the listbox datasource to the binding source
then added following code :

```
Private Sub Onderzoeken_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Tbl_DossiersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Dossiers)
        Me.Tbl_OnderzoeksTypesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_OnderzoeksTypes)
        Dim dt = Tbl_OnderzoeksTypesBindingSource
        cboxOnderzoek.DataSource = dt
        cboxOnderzoek.DisplayMember = "OZ_TypeOnderzoek"
        cboxOnderzoek.ValueMember = "OZ_ID"
        rtbBeschrijvingOnderzoek.Text = dt(0)("OZ_TypeOnderzoek").ToString
        cboxOnderzoek.Focus()

Private Sub CboxDiagnose_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxOnderzoek.SelectionChangeCommitted
        rtbBeschrijvingOnderzoek.Text = DirectCast(cboxOnderzoek.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("OZ_Onderzoeksbeschrijving").ToString
        Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\GoogleDrive\EINDWERK VBNET\PatientenDatabase.accdb")
        cn.Open()
        Dim ssql As String = "Select Rel_ID, tbl_Relaties.Rel_Naam &' ' & Rel_Voornaam as totaleNaam " &
            "From tbl_Relaties INNER Join (tbl_Dossiers INNER Join tbl_DossRelatie On " &
            "tbl_Dossiers.Dos_ID = tbl_DossRelatie.DR_DossID) ON tbl_Relaties.Rel_ID = tbl_DossRelatie.DR_RelID WHERE OZ_ID = " & cboxOnderzoek.SelectedValue

        Dim cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(ssql, cn)
        Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Application.DoEvents()
            bs_Relaties.DataSource = dr
            lboxOZpatientcombo.DisplayMember = "totaleNaam"
            lboxOZpatientcombo.ValueMember = "Rel_ID"

        End If
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

since i added a binding source, the rest was easier to do:

```
   Private Sub lboxOZpatientcombo_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboxOZpatientcombo.DoubleClick
        Try
            Dim MPF As New MainPatientform
            MPF.display(Me, bs_Relaties.Current("rel_id"))
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

thanks to all for new insights in this matter.